# Filtering imported MNIST data

Tags: filtering

I am using the following to import MNIST Data:

```
data = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "MNIST"}, "TrainingData"]
```

How do I get just the data for specific digits e.g. 2,5, 6 etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: One way `Cases[data, Rule[image_, value_] /; MemberQ[{2, 5, 6}, value]  ]`.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. If you make it an answer, I will mark it as accepted. thanks.